# How to understand when user touch the screen in android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to know when user touch the screen? 
Actually i want to know user is using the phone or not. And i thought if user doesn't touch the screen he/she doesn't use the phone. I've already goggled it but i couldn't find any proper things, that's why i want to ask this question in here, and i couldn't find any similar question in here.
I find some code like this :

```
 @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
       }
```

but i don't know how to use properly.
thanks in advance.

Comment: read MotionEvent documentation

Comment: Do you mean in your app, or outside of your app? if it's outside, I don't think there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the last touch of screen using

```
System.curTimeMillis();
```

And use

```
 long lastTouchTime;
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    lastTouchTime = System.curTimeMillis();
    return true;
 }
```

**Or you can check is screen touched now or not :**

```
 boolean isScreenTouchedNow;
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction())
    { 
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            isScreenTouched = true;
            break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isScreenTouched = false;
            break;
    } 
    return true;
 }

 public boolean isScreenTouchedNow()
 {
      return isScreenTouched;
 }
```