# Is android.view.View touched now?

Tags: android, touch

Sure, the [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) event will let me know whenever the user interacts with the view, so toggling a flag according to the *getActionMasked()* state of *MotionEvent* should supply this information. But I have found this method to fall short of the desired result at times.

Is there a more straight forward way to simply ask if a user is currently touching a view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578340/how-to-understand-when-user-touch-the-screen-in-android/22578487#22578487

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote to @bstar55, your first suggestion will not work if the user can touch a view without moving (not as hard as it sounds). Your second suggestion is basically the method I outline above.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking out the documentation for onUserInteraction().

Something like this would allow you to know how recently the user has interacted with the screen:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If a user touches a view and does not move, this event will not be triggered. Some devices are insensitive enough to enable users to touch a view for over 10 seconds, without triggering this event.